# Webpack: Does the order of plugins matter?

Tags: webpack

I looked it up at the docs [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html) and [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-plugins.html), searched StackOverflow and GitHub discussions and still can't find this information. Is there any resource or does anyone knows if the order of the plugins matter in Webpack? And how does the ordering work?

Answer (score 92):

Yes, the order matters: plugins are bound to the compiler and applied in the order specified. You can look into [`webpack/tapable`](https://github.com/webpack/tapable) for a clearer idea on how this works.

Usually, though, you are not forced to think about ordering when binding compiler and compilation plugins, as plugin authors expose [specific events](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/9b272cfb2bccee98bbe8438c817c4207a0a3cb71#events) that help you reason when your handlers will be invoked.

Comment: This could be more clear in the documentation :/. A year later and I'm still searching for the same thing.

Comment: How does that link show how to set up the build order for a node project?

Comment: There are many questions unanswered. How the order on the `webpack.config.js` `plugins` array affects the build process? Are plugins executed after or before loaders? Can webpack plugins be chained in series or parallel in the same way than gulp? I can see the `tapable` package offers some of that functionality. But it's hard to tell how the whole plugin system works in the end without a clearer explanation.

Comment: so they're applied top to bottom or left to right (depending on formatting)?

Answer (score 6):

Well, the answer is **yes** and **no**.

**No** because during the bundling, webpack emits several events which are fired at different phases of the compilation (you can read more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#hooks)).

Each plugin must be hooked (by the plugin's author) to one of these events.

That being said, let's consider two plugins, `A` and `B`.

Even if `A` is listed before `B` in the config file, `A` will be executed before `B` only if it is hooked to an event that is fired before `B`'s hooked event.

**Yes** because in case `A` and `B` are hooked to the same event, the execution order should be consistent with the order in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

> webpack is not a task runner.
> These plugins are tasks, which is not "webpack-style" and not supported. You can report the issue there, but there is nothing to do on webpack side (and I don't care much).
> -sokra

[ref](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4528)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @zr0gravity7 The creator of Webpack says that the order of plugins is not respected and closed the issue requesting this feature in the link