# Add stylesheet link dynamically into html using webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, mini-css-extract-plugin

Would like to run webpack where it creates the appropriate stylesheet link in the header of the html file after using the mini-css-extract-plugin-- similar to how the html-webpack-plugin adds the appropriate JS bundle (script tag) into the html.  Is it possible to have webpack + plugin do this, or do I have to manually stick the stylesheet tag (in the html template)?

Running webpack 4.28

Answer (score 2):

I believe this webpack config should solve your issue.

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

As I was trying to answer this same question, the important part for me to understand was that the order for rules and plugins matter in webpack. (webpack processes the last item in each array first then continues until it gets to the first item... This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470771/webpack-does-the-order-of-plugins-matter) supports this, as well as Sean Larkin's tutorial on Front End Masters.)

That being the case you need to have the "MiniCSSExtractPlugin" come AFTER "HtmlWebpackPlugin" in the plugins array.

You'll also of course need to have the sass file and index.js file in your /src folder and have `import './style.scss'` included in your index.js - you'll also need an index.html in /src if you're going to use the template option for HtmlWebpackPlugin as I did in the config file. Altogether this should output a main.css file, a bundle.js file, and an index.html with a link and script tag included, all within the "dist" folder.